# Who is commentator Pishacha on Brahma Sutras?

Tags: history, vedanta, brahma-sutras, dvaita

Narayana Panditacharya [gave](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=FVtpFMPMulcC&lpg=PP1&dq=bnk+sharma+21+commentators&pg=PA98&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) a list of 21 commentators on the Brahma Sutras who preceded Madhvacharya.

Here is the screenshot of 21 commentators:

[image]

I want to know who is this commentator *Pishacha*? The name is interesting because Pishachas are a race of demons described in Hindu scripture.

Answer (score 1):

It is mentioned in the preface of the Bhagavad Gita published by the Udbodhan Karyalaya of the Ramakrishna Mission, that the Paisaacha Vashya of Gita was written by 'Hanuman'. This may provide some link to the query.