# Did any Rishi tell that Lord Hanuman would compose Brahma Sutra Bhashya?

Tags: ramayana, hanuman, brahma-sutras, dvaita, madhvacharya

I read somewhere, that in Valmiki Ramayana, its written that Valmiki or some other Rishi predicted that Lord Hanuman would compose Brahma Sutra Bhashya in future.

Is this true?

Where exactly in Ramayana is it mentioned?

Comment: No such mention in Valmiki Ramayana that I’ve read

Comment: There is a general belief about Dvaita followers that hanuman was reborn as bheema who was reborn as madhva acharya and wrote the brahma sutra bhasya. After this kalpa, hanuman will become brahma and will write a bhashya of brahma sutra bhashya in the future. Such sentences can not be found in Valmiki Ramayana but may be there in a local Ramayana.

Comment: Related post (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/18996/who-is-commentator-pishacha-on-brahma-sutras).

Comment: @GIRIBLR Yes, they say there is verse in Ramayana which says this

Comment: @PrasannaR do you know anything. I saw this in one if the Madhwa mutt websites.